# GFI Leviton installation corrected

Tags: electrical, smart-switch

I corrected the Load and Line wires and now the green light is off but when i try to reset it just keeps popping out, i dont have anything plugged in for it to surge from, what do i do now?

Comment: What all is on the LOAD side of this GFI?

Comment: And why do  you want it protected?  Or do you just want to connect onward power to it.

Comment: Pictures would help.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for not being able to reset a GFCI after performing work on the circuits is miswiring the GFCI. Verify both your source or line side circuit neutral and hot conductor are connected to the Line side of the GFCI and the Load side circuit neutral and hot conductor is connected to the correct terminal. The neutral must be separated and fed though GFCI device also. So no pigtails. This is a common mistake and has happened to many professionals myself included.

I can't definitely say this is the problem but it is a good start. Good luck.